# How do I change the Windows 10 default boot Volume?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot

I have two hard drives in my computer that each have Windows 10 installed on them. On boot, I am asked which volume I would like to boot from with the top option selected by default after I think 10 seconds.

I am trying to customize which one is selected by default. I tried unplugging the drive I didn't want to boot from, but on boot there were still two options with the default one having no volume name (other option was the drive that was still plugged in).

Is there a way to change which one is selected by default, and is there way to get the other drive not to show up at all in the list?

I apologize if this has been answered before, all searches kept only talking about audio volume.

Comment: Windows 7 you can change it in system properties Advanced tab>startup and recovery button, there is a drop down list of which you want first. In W10 go to control Panel>System>Advanced system settings>Startup and recovery button. Or right click on This PC icon and select Properties, if you have it on the desktop.